# Why typeof getResponseHeader is object even if null?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if `getResponseHeader('X-CUSTOM-DATA')` is set but it always return `object` when I do type check.

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, response, settings) {
      
      var data = response.getResponseHeader('X-CUSTOM-DATA');
      console.log(data); // Return null.
      console.log(typeof data) // return object
      
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is this usual? How do I check if `X-CUSTOM-DATA` is set?

Comment: Just check if it's `null`?

Comment: I don't see why `data === null` would not suffice. [`null` is what jQuery returns if no match](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/70605c8e5655da996ebd395e3c43423daaa08d9c/src/ajax.js#L458).

Comment: Thanks, data === null solved it. I thought, like mysql I cannot check null with null.